# Plotting two data sets in Octave

Tags: plotting, octave

I have two data vectors $y1$ and $y2$, and I want to plot both of them as functions of the vector $x$. I want the result to be two overlapping curves. Here is the set of commands I am using.

y2=[0.003,0.003,0.011,0.011,0.015,0.020,0.023,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.025,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.024,0.023,0.023,0.021,0.019,0.019,0.018,0.016,0.013,0.011,0.009,0.009,0.009];
y1=[0.003,0.003,0.003,0.010,0.031,0.050,0.060,0.065,0.070,0.074,0.079,0.085,0.087,0.087,0.091,0.090,0.090,0.086,0.083,0.079,0.074,0.062,0.055,0.047,0.044,0.035,0.032,0.026,0.018,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.003];
x=[20,70,100,150,200,220,240,250,260,270,280,290,300,310,320,330,340,350,360,370,380,400,450,500,550,600,700,800,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000];
plot(x,y1,y2).

Which does plot the vectors, except that $y2$ is mapped from 0 to 20, while $y1$ is mapped from 20 to 3000. Here is the result from the above command. [image]

$y2$ is the orange graph. I can't really describe the problem any better than this. How should I rewrite my commands so that $y2$ is also mapped from 20 to 3000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

plot(x,[y1;y2])

but make sure that y2 is of the same size as y1, because in your example that isn't the case.